# How to get values which are not present in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned tables:

Table_1

```
ID     Var1   Var2
1      123    10
2      456    12
3      789    11
4      112    14
```

Table_2

```
ID     Value2   Freq
1      123      5
2      555      4
3      779      7
4      112      8
```

I want those `Var1` which are not present in `Table_2`.

Output:

```
ID     Var1   Var2
1      456    12
4      789    11
```

I have tried this:

```
select *
from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.Var1 = t2.Value2
where t1.Var1 not in t2.Value2
```

Comment: The table1 value 123 exists in table2 as well, but you still want it?

Comment: But in your output you need presenting values only. Are you sure the question is correct?

Comment: You question is not clear .. you data sample is not coherent

Comment: Thanks...i have changed the question.

Comment: The ID in your output doesn't seem to correspond to the ID in Table_1 or Table_2. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1 WHERE NOT Var1 IN (SELECT Value2 FROM Table_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table_1
where Var1 not in (select Value2 from Table_2)
```

or

```
select ID, Var1, Var2
from Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2 on t1.Var1 = t2.Value2
where t1.Var1 is null
```

The second way may more efficiently.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN query would return blank, since you're selecting from T1, it should be `WHERE t2.ID IS NULL` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ca7c0/1

Comment: ...or possibly the first way,

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following :

```
select * from Table_1  t1
left join Table_2  t2 on t1.var1=t2.var2
where t2.var2 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM table_1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM table_2 B
                 WHERE A.Var1=B.Var1);
```

See it [run on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e4591/3).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the expected output.

```
SELECT ID, Var1, Var2 
FROM Table_1 
WHERE  Var1 NOT IN (SELECT Value2 FROM Table_2);
```

The `NOT IN` operator is used when you want to retrieve a column that has no entries in the table or referencing table.
I have attached my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6e381/3) with this. You can check it. Good Luck!